# Should I implement a key store / key management system into my python library?

Tags: rsa, aes, hybrid-encryption

I've created a python library that uses both RSA and AES encryption to allow for hybrid encryption of text or images. I am wondering if I should implement a keystore and/or a better key management system and if that would be applicable or useful for my purposes (I plan to implement this in a chat flask web-app). Additionally I would like to know if my library is cryptographically secure and if I can make any improvements to my code in order to make it more efficient. Here is the code for my library:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa, padding
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import io


class RSAEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048)
            self.public_key = self.private_key.public_key()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error generating RSA key: ", e)

    def encrypt(self, data):
        try:
            ciphertext = self.public_key.encrypt(data, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
            return ciphertext
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting data with RSA: ", e)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        try:
            plaintext = self.private_key.decrypt(ciphertext, padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None))
            return plaintext.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting data with RSA: ", e)


class AESEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.key = Fernet.generate_key()
            self.cipher = Fernet(self.key)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error generating AES key: ", e)

    def encrypt(self, data):
        try:
            ciphertext = self.cipher.encrypt(data)
            return ciphertext
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting data with AES: ", e)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        try:
            plaintext = self.cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
            return plaintext.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting data with AES: ", e)


class HybridEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rsa_encryption = RSAEncryption()
        self.aes_encryption = AESEncryption()

    def encrypt_text(self, text):
        try:
            aes_ciphertext = self.aes_encryption.encrypt(text)
            encrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.encrypt(self.aes_encryption.key)
            return aes_ciphertext, encrypted_key
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting text: ", e)

    def decrypt_text(self, aes_ciphertext, encrypted_key):
        try:
            decrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.decrypt(encrypted_key)
            aes_decryption = Fernet(decrypted_key)
            plaintext = aes_decryption.decrypt(aes_ciphertext)
            return plaintext.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting text: ", e)

    def encrypt_image(self, image_path, chunk_size=1024):
        try:
            with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
                data = io.BytesIO(image_file.read())
                chunks = iter(lambda: data.read(chunk_size), b'')
                encrypted_chunks = []
                for chunk in chunks:
                    encrypted_chunk = self.aes_encryption.encrypt(chunk)
                    encrypted_chunks.append(encrypted_chunk)
            encrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.encrypt(self.aes_encryption.key)
            return encrypted_chunks, encrypted_key
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error encrypting image: ", e)

    def decrypt_image(self, encrypted_chunks, encrypted_key, image_path):
        try:
            decrypted_key = self.rsa_encryption.decrypt(encrypted_key)
            aes_decryption = Fernet(decrypted_key)
            decrypted_data = b''.join([aes_decryption.decrypt(chunk) for chunk in encrypted_chunks])
            with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
                image_file.write(decrypted_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error decrypting image: ", e)
```

Comment: Code review is off-topic. Without ability to export and import a public key, asymmetric encryption does not achieve anything useful for telecomunication. Without ability to store private/secret key, a power loss makes encrypted data undecipherable. If `encrypt_text` accepts to encrypt `b'\xFF'` (as I think it does), figure out what `decrypt_text` does of the corresponding ciphertext. What about specifying the input and output types (as modern python supports)? What about [docstring](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/)?

Comment: Try posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)